# What's the motivation to define the unit of current as fundamental in SI system?

Tags: electric-current, units, si-units, metrology

The charge in electromagnetism seemingly plays the same role like mass in the Newtonian mechanics.But why we define the current unit (Ampere) in [SI system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units) as the fundamental rather than charge unit?

Answer (score 2):

We could've chosen Tesla as an S.I. unit. We could've chosen Farad as an S.I. unit. While these units (Tesla and Farad) are used often when we talk about electronics, they aren't used by the common people whereas the current appears in our daily lives.

You wouldn't want to say  "give me a 15 kilogram per tesla second-squared fuse".

Isn't coulomb per second simple? It is simple if you have passed high school. The common people will simply freak out when you use such terms. Ampere seems to be a nice and one word.

Another reason could be by the definition of ampere. Ampere is defined by measuring the force between two current carrying wires. The wires are of course carrying charge but using current is more descriptive.